# Python modules scope

Tags: python, module, scope

Let's say I have a module in Python called `foo`, which has a function `bar()` and a global variable within the module `x = 'spam'`. `bar()` uses this x to operate.

If I import `foo` like `import foo`, then call `foo.bar()`, it's pretty obvious what will happen.

However if I import `bar()` only like this: `from foo import bar`, and I call `bar()`, what will happen if I also have a variable `x` in my global namespace?

foo.py

```
x = 'spam'
def bar():
    print x
```

main.py

```
from foo import bar
x = 'eggs'
bar()
```

What if I replace the import line by this: `from foo import bar, x`?

EDIT: (in both case it prints 'spam', the question is why?)

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: I did, I'm interested in the why, obviously. :)

Comment: The statement `from foo import x` looks up the value of `foo.x` and binds `x` in the local namespace of `main` to the value it finds. The variables `foo.x` and `main.x` are **distinct**, but happen to hold the same value. Assigning a different value to one will not affect the other. [I can't post this as an answer because the question is closed].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`from foo import bar` imports foo (without reference), and creates a local `bar` referenced to `foo.bar`

`bar` has no way of seeing `main.x`

---

You could do a *similar* thing like this:

```
import foo
bar = foo.bar
del foo
```

(Unless you already had an object named `foo`, which is now gone)

Answer (score 2):

Functions are objects that keep various information about themself at creation time.
Check values of `bar.__module__` and `bar.__globals__`, and it will be obvious how it works.